# How i can loadHTMLFile and settime out

Tags: php, settimeout, mpdf

I want to use mPDF to save data, But i am not very good in PHP. 
This is my code.

```
<?php
include("mpdf/mpdf.php");

$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($_GET['page'].'.php?fdlDate='.$_GET['fdlDate']);
$doc->setTimeout(7000);

$getContent = $doc->getElementById('content');

$mpdf=new mPDF('th','A4',0,'',10,10,20,10,10,'');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($getContent);
$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

It have a error.

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;taxAPrint.php?fdlDate=2015-06-23&quot; in ...\mPDF.php on line 5

Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::setTimeout() in ...\mPDF.php on line 6
```

What wrong? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: **What wrong ?** `Same Question to you !`

Comment: Yeah man you need to actually explain your problem not let everyone guess what it might be

Comment: What is it that's not working? Tell is what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

[DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) does not have a method called `setTimeout()`, which is why you cannot set a timeout and get the fatal error.

You also have a warning that the file you're trying to load in `loadHTMLFile()`  can't be found. You might want to use `var_dump()` to check the values that you're passing in and make sure that they make sense from the server's perspective. Remember that the server does not make any assumptions at all and will do what you tell it to do, literally.